# How to get result history of specific testcase using tfs-sdk

Tags: tfs-sdk, microsoft-test-manager

I have automated testcase in Test Manager. This testcase was executed several times in different builds (It is situated in several test runs). I can see history of test execution through Test Manager UI (Test Manager -> Analyze Test Runs -> Open Test Run -> View Results for Testcase -> Result History table).

How to get same data using TFS API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```cs
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                new Uri(@"http://<yourTFS>:8080/tfs/<your collection>"),
                new System.Net.NetworkCredential(<user who can access to TFS>,<password>));
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

ITestManagementService testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

var testRuns = testManagementService.QueryTestRuns("SELECT * FROM TestRun WHERE TestRun.TestPlanId=<your test plan ID>");

IEnumerable<ITestCaseResult> testResultHistoryYouWant = from testRun in testRuns
                                from testResult in testRun.QueryResults()
                                where testResult.TestCaseId == <your test case ID>
                                select testResult;
```

Comment: It's just what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you recommend me some articles about this: "SELECT * FROM TestRun WHERE TestRun.TestPlanId=<our test plan ID>" and this: from testRun in testRuns from testResult in testRun.QueryResults() where testResult.TestCaseId == <your test case ID> select testResult;

Comment: This one was very helpful for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/duat_le/archive/2010/02/25/wiql-for-test.aspx

Comment: This could be useful for you, too: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/10/02/mtm-testing-scorecard-using-tfs-api.aspx